# Command line arguments to Boost UTF unit_test_main

Tags: c++, memory-corruption, boost-unit-test-framework

I have my own Boost Test Runner where I pass the arguments to `unit_test_main` like this:

```
char *myargs[] = {"", "--log_level=test_suite", "report_level=detailed", "output_format=xml", "--run_test=my_manual_test_suite1,my_manual_test_suite2"};
```

The test suites are picked up, the test cases are executed. However, at the end of my program execution, I get a memory corruption. Is there a reason why?

My test runner is a single cpp file which houses all the test cases and also the `unit_test_main`.

EDIT: I forgot to add there is no corruption if I pass the arguments from outside my program. This is weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you share some more code? I want to see the difference you made in passing the arguments locally vs. passing them from outside the program.

EDIT:

Ok, I think I got the problem. When you pass in arguments from outside they are laid out sequentially. For example lets say you call `test.exe --log_level=all --run_test=mt1`. The address of the first arg is 0x10000, say. Then the address of the next arg `--log_level=all` begins at 0x10009 and so on. When you string up the argv yourself, this is not the case. So my suggestion would be to lay the arguments sequentially like above and give it a try.

Comment: When they came from outside, it was like this: `int main (int argc, char **argv)` I passed the same argv to `unit_test_main` and then no memory corruption happened. However if I construct my own argv as `char **myargv = {...};` the memory corruption is seen. I would be happy to post the entire code sample but don't know how. Thanks for the prompt response!

Comment: Ok, I think I got the problem. When you pass in arguments from outside they are laid out sequentially. For example lets say you call `test.exe --log_level=all --run_test=mt1`. The address of the first arg is 0x10000, say. Then the address of the next arg `--log_level=all` begins at 0x10009 and so on. When you string up the argv yourself, this is not the case. So my suggestion would be to lay the arguments sequentially like above and give it a try.

Comment: Thanks. This solution worked. When I pass the args and they are laid out sequentially, there is no memory corruption. I am marking this as answer.